# list product and image with relation foreignkey

Tags: django-templates, django-views

this is my model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()

class Image(models.Model):
    nombre = models.ImageField(upload_to=url)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

i need to list all product and someone images related.

And using in my view:

```
Product.objects.all()
```

But, i need at least one image to list.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use relationships.

```
obj = Product.image_set.all()[:0]
```

will return you list with one image object. Then you can manage with it. If you want to get it in template then use

```
{% for x in myobject.image_set.all %}
    {{ x.nombre }}
{% endfor %}
```